# %temp% folder files delete

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, temporary-files

In my windows server 2008r2 i was running out of free space
I have deleted following folder contents

- C:\Windows\Temp
- C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue

But when i run %temp% in run it navigates to `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3`
I was expecting it to navigate to `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\`
Can i delete contents of `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\` or only `C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\3` ?

What is the actual temp path?

Comment: Another place that you can look to get some space back is in c:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download.  All the windows update servicepacks and patches gets downloaded here.  After you installed everything you can delete all the files in the download folder.  Should get you a bit of bytes back.

Comment: @StBlade Nice. Is there any other folders which i can delete? Please share.

Comment: You can also remove all the profiles of the users that do not login to the server anymore.  Right click Computer -> properties -> Advanced system settings -> Advanced -> User Profiles.  BE CAREFUL!!  Only remove users that do not login to the server anymore.  Otherwise you are going to get a lot of angry emails and telephone calls.

Comment: @StBlade: It helps if the windows update service gets stopped before you try to delete (start, run, `net stop wuauserv`).

Comment: @Hennes This will help, if you find a particular update in the download folder that does not want to delete.  From experience, I just made sure that all updates were installed and deleted the files without any problems.  This in a local and WSUS enviroment.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the "Local" (same as 2003 "Local settings") holds only caches, so deleting it shouldn't cause any problems.

Also, note that this folder isn't copied when using roaming profiles (it's created upon logon), so it's clearly deletable.

Comment: But why %temp% is set to folder 3 inside temp? Also its safe to delete temp/*.* ?

Comment: It's safe assuming there are no open handles to any files...
Safest way would be to delete this contents when the user is offline.

Comment: As for the number 3, it seem like some random meaningless number.